# How to run Swift plugin from SonarQube for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am for the first time trying to integrate SonarQube on a test iOS project on my local system. I have downloaded and successfully installed SonarQube and SonarScanner. I have also downloaded latest(0.4.6) bakelite Sonar Swift plugin from [here](https://github.com/Idean/sonar-swift/releases).

Following is my Sonar Scanner file content:

```html
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=Vivy@123

sonar.projectKey=testSonar1
sonar.projectName=testSonar

# Number version (can be found automatically in plist, just comment this line)
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Comment if you have a project with mixed ObjC / Swift
sonar.language=swift
# Project description
sonar.projectDescription=Project Description
# Path to source directories
sonar.sources=.
# Path to test directories (comment if no test)
sonar.tests=testSonarTests,testSonarUITests
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
sonar.test.inclusions=*.swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*

# Destination Simulator to run surefire
# As string expected in destination argument of xcodebuild command
# Example = sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.2
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=latest
# Xcode project configuration (.xcodeproj)
# and use the later to specify which project(s) to include in the analysis (comma separated list)
# Specify either xcodeproj or xcodeproj + xcworkspace
sonar.swift.project=testSonar.xcodeproj
#sonar.swift.workspace=testSonar.xcworkspace
# Specify your appname.
# This will be something like "myApp"
# Use when basename is different from targeted scheme.
# Or when slather fails with 'No product binary found'
sonar.swift.appName=testSonar
# Scheme to build your application
sonar.swift.appScheme=testSonar
# Configuration to use for your scheme. if you do not specify that the default will be Debug
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug
##########################
# Optional configuration #
##########################
# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
# SCM
# sonar.scm.enabled=true
# sonar.scm.url=scm:git:http://xxx
# JUnit report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
# The XML files have to be prefixed by TEST- otherwise they are not processed
sonar.junit.reportsPath=sonar-reports/
# Lizard report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/lizard-report.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.lizard.report=sonar-reports/lizard-report.xml
# Cobertura report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/coverage-swift.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/cobertura.xml
# OCLint report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/oclint.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.swiftlint.report=sonar-reports/swiftlint.txt
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
#sonar.swift.tailor.report=sonar-reports/*tailor.txt
# Paths to exclude from coverage report (surefire, 3rd party libraries etc.)
sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=build,DerivedData,fastlane,Pods,reports,testSonarTests,testSonarUITests,xcov_output
sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=.*Tests.*
##########################
# Tailor configuration #
##########################
# Tailor configuration
# -l,--max-line-length=<0-999>                  maximum Line length (in characters)
#    --list-files                               display Swift source files to be analyzed
#    --max-class-length=<0-999>                 maximum Class length (in lines)
#    --max-closure-length=<0-999>               maximum Closure length (in lines)
#    --max-file-length=<0-999>                  maximum File length (in lines)
#    --max-function-length=<0-999>              maximum Function length (in lines)
#    --max-name-length=<0-999>                  maximum Identifier name length (in characters)
#    --max-severity=<error|warning (default)>   maximum severity
#    --max-struct-length=<0-999>                maximum Struct length (in lines)
#    --min-name-length=<1-999>                  minimum Identifier name length (in characters)
sonar.swift.tailor.config=--no-color --max-line-length=100 --max-file-length=500 --max-name-length=40 --max-name-length=40 --min-name-length=4
```

When I execute my sonar scanner I get Execution Success message. But when I go to my sonar console there I get bugs related to some html or python file. I am not getting anything related to Swift generated there. Please check the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I feel that somehow Sonar plugin is not getting mapped with SonarQube. Also, I can see that SonarFiles are generated as below:

[image]

How can I fix it in order to get my SonarQube running?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help you with this or your iOS project when there is nothing in the question that shows how you are trying to integrate this third party solution (or even has any relevance to Swift).

Comment: it is an empty project, I just want to learn SonarQube integration so that I can integrate it in my main project.

Comment: how do you run this scan? also add some issue with swift code, for example make a function with an unused paramter (e.g. `func x(a: Int) { print("hello") }`) - maybe it just doesn't have anything to report

Comment: I tried to add above code but it is not reflecting in sonar. It is showing defects in distribute_setup.py and report.html file. I am not sure why it is picking these files and not Swift files and also not sure what is distribute_setup.py file, possibly added during sonar scanning

Comment: I have now removed distribute_setup.py but it is still showing errror in reports.html but no Swift file.

Comment: The problem is it is not showing any Swift file under tab Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was fine. In addition to installing the sonarqube as mentioned above I had also installed another version from homebrew. so when I was trying to run Sonar I was actually running sonar from brew and not the above one. Sonar from brew did not contain any plugin so I was not able to scan my Swift code.